# Suggestions For Additional Neural Network Test Cases

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Was wondering if anyone can provide some good test cases for testing multilayer neural netowrks, beyond the basic XOR problem. This is for use with Backpropogation, but hopefully they will be universal.  I didn't know if there were some good already-established datasets, or suggestions for problems in which I might need to (easily) compile the data myself.

Yes, I know that most problems which are considered linearly inseperable are good candidates, but it has been difficult for me to come up with multiple tests for validating the network.

Answer (score 0):

Point is that you train neural network for one purpose, and by comparing computed outputs with expected you validate your network.

You cant train your network for something (XOR for example) and then validy it by other function. To validy it with other function you have to train it for that function first, and network will forget previous function.

When you are validating XOR example, you only see that neural network is capable of learning (because it learned XOR example) thus any other tests are not necessary

If you insist of validating network on multiple datasets, you can create it yourself. Just pick some random values as input and random values as expected output.
Then train neural network until it gives you expected output on provided input. 
But xor example is the same, you can think of it like random data

Comment: No, no, no!  Sorry, I am misusing the technical terms of 'testing' and 'validation' for neural networks.  I mean to 'test' the underlying algorithms I have implemented, such as Backpropogation and such.  I want to know if the program itself is functioning correctly beyond that of the XOR problem.

Comment: Point is that if its functioning correctly for XOR problem, it wont have difficulities with other problems. Its like if you had a car that works (you tried) and you demanded how to validate if it works by other method than taking a ride in it. ;)

Comment: Well, no.  I would subject it to multiple types of stress tests including different climates, travel cross-country, underwater... see how high I can jump it off a ramp.  Or off a ramp and into the water.

Comment: You can do none of those with a neural network, though.